# How would I pass data using protocols from my View Controller to a container within it?

Tags: swift, xcode, delegates, containers, protocols

How would I pass the string value in my ViewController into the Container using a protocol with a delegate?

```
protocol VCDelegate {
    func passData(theData:String)        
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var delegate : VCDelegate?

@IBAction func getRestaurantInformation(_ sender: Any) {

    let ViewC = ViewController()
    let ContainerV = ContainerView()      

    ViewC.delegate = ContainerV
    ViewC.delegate?.passData(theData: "pass this text")

}
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

}


class ContainerView: UIViewController, FirstVCDelegate {


func passData(theData: String) {

    print(theData)
    textLabelOut.text = theData //it leaves an error "found nil while implicitly unwrapping optional value"

}


@IBOutlet weak var textLabelOut: UILabel!

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

}
}
```

I keep getting the error "Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value". But from what I understand the value isn't nil. It is printing out. It just wont pass it to the text label

Answer (score 1):

You should load the container with

```
let containerV = self.storyboard!.......
```

not

```
let containerV = ContainerView()
```

as it makes all outlets nil

---

Don't access outlets of a vc until it's presented

```
ViewC.delegate?.passData(theData: "pass this text")
```

because even if you load it from storyboard , also outlets are nil until it loads

Comment: This works as far as transferring my data. But it makes my container the full screen when the button is pressed. How would i go about transferring the data while not changing the container size ?

Comment: may be you need to set `ContainerV.view.frame = ///`